# value of queryselected/getElementByClass returns value as empty

Tags: javascript

when I try to querySelect an Element from another module, it always returns empty string ? what should do to fix this? the element exists because when i console log it, the element is there, just the value always returns empty even after i have filled the input in UI, its just that when i press submit its returning empty.

furthermore, if i move the code to the scope where the function is being exported, it works

below code is inside the function footerSubmitSection() that is being exported to another module called addNewOrderFormMain.js where all the components is being appended to the main container and exported to the index.js

the console.log returns

```
// order ID
        db.collection('UserDatabase').doc(currentUserID).get().then((doc) => {

                function dateForOrder(){
                    let today = new Date();
                    let dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
                    let mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
                    let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                    today = mm+dd+yyyy;
                    return today
                } 

                let todayOrderNum = db.collection('OrderDatabase').where('OrderDate', '==', `${orderDate}`)
                    .get()
                    .then((snapshot) => {
                        length = snapshot.size + 1;
                        let salesRepID = doc.data().SaleID
                        let salesRepName = doc.data().Name
                        let orderID = salesRepID + dateForOrder()+'-'+ length + "-"+ editversion
                 
                        console.log(deliveryMethodInput)
                        if (deliveryMethodInput=== 'Pick Up'){
                            const pickupLocationInput = document.getElementsByClassName('orderDetailSectionMidPickupLocationSelect')[0].value;
                            let pickupLocation = pickupLocationInput;
                             db.collection('OrderDatabase').doc(orderID).set({
                                    PickupLocation:pickupLocation,
                                    ShippingAddress:"",
                                    BusinessName:businessName,
                                    CustomerType:customerType,
                                    BillingAddress:billingAddress,
                                    CustomerPhoneNumber:customerPhoneNum,
                                    DeliveryMethod:deliveryMethod,
                                    ShipOrPickDate:shipOrPickDate,
                                    PaymentMethod:paymentMethod,
                                    Notes:notes,
                                    OrderDate:orderDate,
                                    OrderStatus:orderStatus,
                                    OrderID:orderID,
                                    salesRepID:salesRepID,
                                    salesRepName:salesRepName,
                            })

                            db.collection('CustomerDatabase').get().then((snapshot) => {
                                snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                                    if(businessNameValue === doc.data().BusinessName){
                                        let customerID = doc.data().CustomerID;
                                        db.collection('OrderDatabase').doc(orderID).update({
                                            CustomerID:customerID,
                                        })
                                    }
                                })
                            })



                            let subtotalArray=[];  /////////////this is the block im having issue with
                            let sum = 0
                            const basket = document.getElementsByClassName('orderProductSectionMidItemContainer')
                            Array.from(basket).forEach((basketItem) => {
                                const basketItemName = basketItem.getElementsByClassName('orderProductSectionMidDisplayItemNameInput')[0];
                                const basketItemPrice = basketItem.getElementsByClassName('orderProductSectionMidDisplayPriceInput')[0];
                                const basketItemQuantity = basketItem.getElementsByClassName('orderProductSectionMidDisplayQuantitiyInput')[0];
                                const basketItemDiscount = basketItem.getElementsByClassName('orderProductSectionMidDisplayDiscountInput')[0];
                                const basketItemSubtotal = basketItem.getElementsByClassName('orderProductSectionMidDisplaySubtotal')[0];
                                subtotalArray.push(basketItemSubtotal.value);
                    
                                console.log(basketItemName.value)
                                console.log(basketItemName.value)
                                console.log(basketItemPrice.value)
                                console.log(basketItemQuantity.value)
                
                                db.collection('OrderDatabase').doc(orderID).collection('Basket').doc('testing').set({
                                    ItemName:basketItemName.value,
                                    ItemPrice:basketItemPrice.value,
                                    ItemQuantity:basketItemQuantity.value,
                                    ItemDiscount:basketItemDiscount.value,
                                    ItemSubtotal:basketItemSubtotal.value ,
                                })
                                console.log(subtotalArray)
                            })
                
                            console.log(basket)
                            for(let i = 0; i < subtotalArray.length; i++){
                                sum += parseFloat(subtotalArray[i]);
                            }/////////////block ends here

                        }else if(deliveryMethodInput === 'Ship'){
                             db.collection('OrderDatabase').doc(orderID).set({
                                    ShippingAddress:shippingAddress,
                                    PickupLocation:"",
                                    BusinessName:businessName,
                                    CustomerType:customerType,
                                    BillingAddress:billingAddress,
                                    CustomerPhoneNumber:customerPhoneNum,
                                    DeliveryMethod:deliveryMethod,
                                    ShipOrPickDate:shipOrPickDate,
                                    PaymentMethod:paymentMethod,
                                    Notes:notes,
                                    OrderDate:orderDate,
                                    OrderStatus:orderStatus,
                                    OrderID:orderID,
                                    salesRepID:salesRepID,
                                    salesRepName:salesRepName,
                                })
                            db.collection('CustomerDatabase').get().then((snapshot) => {
                                snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                                    if(businessNameValue === doc.data().BusinessName){
                                        let customerID = doc.data().CustomerID;
                                        db.collection('OrderDatabase').doc(orderID).update({
                                            CustomerID:customerID,
                                        })
                                    }
                                })
                            })

                        }
                
                    })

        

            })
```

Comment: there is no `querySelect` function in JS, from where did you pick this one ?

Comment: Please don't post such large code file. Just show use the relevant part. It's hard to navigate and fine out the error.

Comment: @MisterJ Joj:  i was originally using querySelector, it didnt work, so i went on and ty getElementByClassname instead, but it still doesn't work.\

Comment: @sifat  my apologies on this, understood i will avoid doing this again. as for the error, i thinking this error is probably caused by how i organize the code.